# Add KeyListener to a JToolTip

Tags: java, swing

I have some code that produces a JToolTip on screen following a user action. I'd like the user to be able to dismiss the tip either by clicking it or hitting a key (ESC, say). I can get the mouse part working, but I can't figure out how/where to catch the key event. I suspect this has something to do with focus, but all my random stabs have been fruitless. Here's a short code sample that shows what I'm attempting:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloSwing extends JFrame {

  HelloSwing() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("Hello!");

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        final JWindow window = new JWindow();
        JToolTip tip = new JToolTip();
        tip.setTipText("Here's a tip...");
        tip.setVisible(true);
        window.getContentPane().add(tip);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocation(50, 50);
        window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        window.setVisible(true);

        // This works:
        window.getRootPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
          @Override
          public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            window.setVisible(false);
          }
        });

        // This does not work:
        window.getRootPane().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
          @Override
          public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("key pressed!");
            window.setVisible(false);
          }
        });
      }
  });      

    panel.add(button);
    add(panel);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HelloSwing hello = new HelloSwing();
    hello.setTitle("Title!");
    hello.setSize(300, 200);
    hello.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    hello.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for key listener to work the component must be focusable and have focus. Key listener is a lower level interface. It is best to use Key Bindings instead. See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details and examples. For example try to the following:

```
getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0, false), "ESCAPE");
getRootPane().getActionMap().put("ESCAPE", new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        window.setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

Note that [ToolTipManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ToolTipManager.html) already registers `VK_ESCAPE` to hide tooltips and in normal cases escape works as expected.

Also note that there is no need to use `JToolTip` in this case since you're using `JWindow` to show it manually. It can simply be a `JLabel`.

See [How to Use Tool Tips](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html) for some examples of usual tooltips use.